# Use parameter value as object instance variable

Tags: java

I want to know how I can use the parameter value to name an object instance variable.

Example:

```
public class Employee (String name, char gender) {
    ...
}
```

In main routine:

```
public static void CreateEmployee (String var, String name, char gender) { 
    Employee var = new Employee (name, gender); // Calls Employee     constructor

}
```

In this case, the way it is, there is a syntax error, since I have a duplicate variable, because I'm declaring var twice. What I want is to use the value of var to name the object.

How can I do that? Is there a method I can use for that?

Thanks!

Comment: So you want the string passed into the `main()` method to be the variable name that you assign your new `Employee` to? The value is only available at run-time, but the variable must be declared at compile-time.

Comment: why do you want to do that? What purpose will you solve by it?

Comment: Suppose this were possible - how are you then going to refer to that `Employee` object? You won't know what the variable name is until you run it...

Comment: To be honest, I was thinking about var.getName(), for example. Would that be possible (I'm just learning Java, btw)?

Comment: But you'd have to name the variable `var` in the first place, to be able to do that, and if you know it's called `var`, there'd be no point having a `getName()` method, since you'd need to already know the name before calling it.

Comment: Well, the getName() here is a getter from an attribute of Employee. In this case, what I meant was I would call CreateEmployee(john, "John Harris, 'M'). My object variable would then be called john, and I was wondering if I could then call this getter using var.getName() (returning "John Harris", in this case) or any other method of Employee, for that matter.

Comment: What does "my object variable would then be called `john`" mean, if you're going to refer to it as `var`? In the latter case, it would be called `var`, not `john`. If you actually want to be able to write `john.getName()`, then again, you won't know what it's name is until you run the `CreateEmployee()` method, and you have to write that method, and therefore know the name of the variable, before you can run it. The next time you run it, someone could pass `susan` at the name instead, and then `john.getName()` isn't going to work.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you want to do that but here is a way

```
public static Map<String, Employee> employeeMap = new HashMap<String, Employee>();
public static void createEmployee(String var, String name, char gender){

    employeeMap.put(var, new Employee(name, gender));
}
```

After the map is populated, you can get any employee by keys of map

```
employeeMap.get(var);
```

Note that you need to have all unique **var**s as they are being put as keys in the map

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I'm learning Java and playing around with it, so I guess it would be good to know how to accomplish some things, even though only for the sake of learning.

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare variable twice within same scope, you can do two things here 
1. Either change the variable name of one of the variable or.
2. Declare `String var` as `Object var` but it replaces the content of parameter i.e String with Employee object.